# Dataframe to SQL db if table exists

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, sqlalchemy

The below snippet will write DataFrame to SQL db,

```
df.to_sql(tablename, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

what it does is .... it writes the data from DataFrame to SQL if a table already exists,
if suppose a table is not created in a db, then it creates the table with tablename which is specified and then it is writing to db.
but I need to write records only when the table already exists in a database..
how to do that, please help me...

Comment: It looks like you have everything you need right here. What, exactly, is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to add a condition before inserting to DB...
and here is the code which I've done...

```
if tablename in  tables:
    df.to_sql(tablename, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I made a list called tables which consists of table names of database and I am checking the table which I need to insert to database is in the list of tables.. if yes, then it will be inserted to database.
and this is what I needed... it works!

Answer (score 0):

.to_sql() doesn't provide the functionality to only add rows if the table exists. .to_sql() only provides the following functionality:

> Tables can be newly created, appended or replaced with

For your requirement, you need to first check if the table exist and if it does then only use the .to_sql().

To check whether table exist use the information_schema and replace YOUR TABLE with your table name:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '<YOUR TABLE>'
```

Function to check if table exist, and if it exist, then do your process in if clause.
In the code below, table_name will be the name of your table.

```
def check_if_table_exist():
    query="Select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = (%s)"
    conn=getConnection()
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    try:
        table_name="bcg"
        cursor.execute(query, (table_name, ))
        result=cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
        if(result):
            print("Table exist")
            # Do your processing here to insert using .to_sql()
        else:
            print("table does not exist")
        pass
    except:
        print("Error")
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
```

Comment: Your answer is good ,but if you can add some example code then that will more helpful.

Comment: @Sachin Have added a function on how to implement it. Let me know if anything else is required.